# How do I get the sum of children within a parent div?

Tags: javascript, sum

I'm attempting to add the sum of children within a parent div, but haven't been able to limit the scope of the math to children of a single parent.

I'm starting with an array:

```
[
  {
    "item1-name": "item1",
    "item1-price": "$100.00",
    "item2-name": "item2",
    "item2-price": "$200.00",
    "item3-name": "item3",
    "item3-price": "300.00",
    "item4-name": "item4",
    "item4-price": "$400.00",
    "total": "$1,000.00"
  },
  {
    "item1-name": "item1",
    "item1-price": "$100.00",
    "item2-name": "item2",
    "item2-price": "$200.00",
    "item3-name": "item3",
    "item3-price": "300.00",
    "item4-name": "",
    "item4-price": "",
    "total": "$0.00"
  },
  {
    "item1-name": "item1",
    "item1-price": "$100.00",
    "item2-name": "item2",
    "item2-price": "$200.00",
    "item3-name": "",
    "item3-price": "",
    "item4-name": "",
    "item4-price": "",
    "total": "0"
  }
]
```

Then I write the contents of the page into html with javascript

```
function values(row){
  return '<div class="container">' +
    '<p>' + row["item1-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' +  
    row["item1-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + row["item2-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' + 
    row["item2-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + row["item3-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' + 
    row["item3-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + row["item4-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' + 
    row["item4-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<h4>Total' + '<span class="value  total">' + row["total"] + 
    '</span></h4>' +
  '</div>';
 };

 var containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

 function findTotals(container){
 $.each(containers, function(){
    var sum = 0;

     $(this).children(".cost").each(function() {
         var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );

         if ( val ) {
             val = parseFloat( val.replace( /^\$/, "" ) );
             sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0;
         }
      });
      alert(sum);
   });
  };

function buildRows(rows){
   var allRows = "";
   rows.forEach(function(row){
   allRows = allRows + admitTemplate(row);
   })

   document.getElementById('rowHolder').innerHTML = allRows;
   findTotals();
}

fetch('queryExport.json')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok){
    return response.json()
  } else {
     return Promise.reject('something went wrong!')
  }
})
.then(rows => {
  buildRows(rows);
})

.catch(error => console.log('error is', error));
```

The problem lies in the findTotals function. I want to limit the sum to the .cost values inside each .container div. (currently the total comes to 1900, when the totals are 1000, 600, 300. (all the .cost values on the page are being added, when I'm really trying to iterate over one .container div at a time, executing the function within the scope of the parent (.container) div.

You can see the totals are broken. My next goal will be to compare the sums to the total value. If they don't match, I'll highlight the broken total value, so the query generating it can be fixed.

Thank you for you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset the value of `sum`, so each iteration of the loop adds to the existing value, rather than being independent.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your selector and DOM construction: $(this).children. Children looks for all the DOM elements that are children, not all descendants.  .cost is not a child element of .container, it is a child element of p. If you replace it with .find, you will get the results.

```js
function findTotals(container) {
  $.each(containers, function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $(this).find(".cost").each(function() {
      var val = $.trim($(this).text());   
      if (val) {
        val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
        sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
      }
    });
    console.log(sum);
  });
};
```

Here's a link to a fiddle that works as well - https://jsfiddle.net/z5oug908/1/

**Updated Answer**

So the more I thought about this, the more I wondered if you really need to be searching the DOM to do a sum of the totals. You have all the data you need in an array already. We can use map, filter and reduce to calculate the totals before you ever render them like this:

```js
function calculateTotals(rows) {
  return rows.map(row => {
    const rowTotal = Object.keys(row).filter(key => {
      const match = key.search(/(price)/gi)
      return match !== -1;
    }).reduce((pre, cur) => {
      let val = row[cur];
      val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
      if (val) {
        return val + pre;
      }
      return pre;
    }, 0);

    row["total"] = rowTotal;
    return row;
  })
}
```

A completed example that *should* work:

```js
function calculateTotals(rows) {
  return rows.map(row => {
    const rowTotal = Object.keys(row).filter(key => {
      const match = key.search(/(price)/gi)
      return match !== -1;
    }).reduce((pre, cur) => {
      let val = row[cur];
      val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
      if (val) {
        return val + pre;
      }
      return pre;
    }, 0);

    row["total"] = rowTotal;
    return row;
  })
}

function admitTemplate(row) {
  return '<div class="container">' +
    '<p>' + row["item1-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' +
    row["item1-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + row["item2-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' +
    row["item2-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + row["item3-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' +
    row["item3-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + row["item4-name"] + '<span class="value  cost">' +
    row["item4-price"] + '</span></p>' +
    '<h4>Total' + '<span class="value  total">' + row["total"] +
    '</span></h4>' +
    '</div>';
};


function buildRows(rows) {
  var allRows = "";
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    allRows = allRows + admitTemplate(row);
  })

  document.getElementById('rowHolder').innerHTML = allRows;
}

fetch('queryExport.json')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('something went wrong!')
    }
  })
  .then(calculateTotals)
  .then(buildRows);
```

Comment: Thank you, Bill. 

This is a step forward. For some reason the if(val) piece isn't functioning for me, but I was able to move the .replace() up to the val variable. I'll work more on figuring out a way to add the values. I expect I need to write an array containing the values to be able to derive a total... more soon.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think you can get by with doing it before it ever hits the DOM, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: One aspect that I didn't make clear—the purpose I'm attempting to achieve is to be able to check a query generated elsewhere. 

The math in the query has been breaking (typically returning a zero value). 

The query contains a couple thousand rows. The steps I'm attempting to complete are 

1. get the sum of prices
2. check against the total from the query
3. (hadn't mentioned this step yet) if the total from the query doesn't match the sum, I'll add a class to the total to highlight it
4. move to the next row and start again

(does sum == total output from query)

Comment: That's fine. I still think you'd want to sum before inserting the nodes into the DOM. Doing that kind of parsing and manipulation will be a lot slower than doing it while you have the data in an array. Instead of assigning row["total"] = rowTotal, change that to row["sum"] = rowTotal and then in the admit template you can add the class if the sum and total are different. No extra parsing necessary.

Comment: Thank you, Bill. I'll give that a try. I think part of my problem lies in my poor understanding of scope. I can find a value inside a function, but can't use it as a variable outside the function to compare to another value contained in a 2nd function. I'm getting some much needed practice, I suppose. thanks again